Can I write a changing integer value to a list in a loop without overwriting the previous value?
I have a for loop with an if statement checking if the current character in 'phrase' is equal to a character in 'dictator[column]' and if it is, it will append the position of a character to a global list 'listY' but every time it tries to append the value of 'column' to 'listY', it overwrites the value that was previously there.
This is the current code for the first part of the code that finds the X and Y of a character in the list 'encryptionTable':
def findCypherP1():
    a = 0 # length of phrase to encrypt (cypher phrase)
    column = 0 # length of encryption section (shuffled alphabet)
    row = 0
    dictator = encryptionTable[0] # first row of the alphabet
    for p in range(len(phrase) * len(dictator)):
        global listY
        listY = []
        if phrase[a] == dictator[column]:
            print("Column containing cypher Y:", str(column+1))
            column2 = column
            listY.append(column2)
            a += 1; column = 0
        if a >= len(phrase):
            print(listY)
            break
        else:
            column += 1

What happens when I run the code is it correctly returns the X value of the characters
Column containing cypher Y: 1
Column containing cypher Y: 11
Column containing cypher Y: 12
Column containing cypher Y: 19
Column containing cypher Y: 3
[2]

But then when it appends 'column' to 'listY', it overwrites the previous value, I've tried making a copy of the int 'column' but it only works on lists. If you could help solve this problem, that would be great! Thank you!

It isn't clear exactly what you were expecting, but you create a new list and assign it to the global variable (objects don't have a scope, variables have a scope) on each iteration of the loop, listY = [].

You shared a function, but no example value of the global variables encryptionTable and phrase you're accessing. Please share examples, or better yet, change your function to accept them as arguments and show how you call the function.

Take listY = [] out of the loop if you don't want to lose the old values

Why are you using a global variable? Make it a local variable and return it at the end.

This is quite simply because you are reintializing listY=[] within your loop right ? If you move it out of the for loop then it should just work. Also in that instance you don't need the global variable ?

You will want to move the initialization of your global variable listY outside of your loop. If listY is inside the loop, it will re-initialize listY every time the loop iterates. Additionally, you might not need a global variable in which case you can just return listY from your function
def findCypherP1():
    listY = []
    a = 0 # length of phrase to encrypt (cypher phrase)
    column = 0 # length of encryption section (shuffled alphabet)
    row = 0
    dictator = encryptionTable[0] # first row of the alphabet
    for p in range(len(phrase) * len(dictator)):
        if phrase[a] == dictator[column]:
            print("Column containing cypher Y:", str(column+1))
            column2 = column
            listY.append(column2)
            a += 1; column = 0
        if a >= len(phrase):
            print(listY)
            break
        else:
            column += 1
    return listY


I feel like an idiot for not realizing I was initializing the list in the loop, but thank you!
